# Not able to push a commit in the main branch

Tags: git, github-actions, git-push

I have made one commit to my local machine, but when I'm trying to push the commit to main branch, I'm facing the below error.

```
git push origin main
remote: Permission to ragnarok/encode-project.git denied to Bhavishyag2.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ragnarok/encode-project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

When I do the above with SSH remote, it gives a different error:

```
encode-project>git push origin main
ERROR: Permission to ragnarok/encode-project.git denied to Bhavishyag2.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

If anyone could help?

Comment: Maybe you have stored invalid credentials on your local machine. Try to re-authenticate.

Comment: `Permission to ragnarok/encode-project.git denied to Bhavishyag2` should be clear enough: you've correctly (?) authenticated to the host as the user named `Bhavishyag2`, and the user named `Bhavishyag2` is not allowed access to that repository.

Answer (score 0):

That means the credentials (username/token) used for accessing ragnarok's repository or the SSH public key registered to GitHub is:

- not ragnarok's
- identify a remote account Bhavishyag2 who is not registered as a collaborator to the `ragnarok/encode-project` project.

If you are Bhavishyag2, you would need to **[fork](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo)** `ragnarok/encode-project` before being able to add/commit and, more importantly, push to that repository.